# How to translate camera in Open3d

Tags: open3d

In Open3D, we can rotate the camera in a Visualization window using our mouse. But how do we translate it? Ideally there is an intuitive keyboard + mouse way, but also the programmatic way is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-- Mouse view control --
  Left button + drag         : Rotate.
  Ctrl + left button + drag  : Translate.
  Wheel button + drag        : Translate.
  Shift + left button + drag : Roll.
  Wheel                      : Zoom in/out.

-- Keyboard view control --
  [/]          : Increase/decrease field of view.
  R            : Reset view point.
  Ctrl/Cmd + C : Copy current view status into the clipboard.
  Ctrl/Cmd + V : Paste view status from clipboard.

-- General control --
  Q, Esc       : Exit window.
  H            : Print help message.
  P, PrtScn    : Take a screen capture.
  D            : Take a depth capture.
  O            : Take a capture of current rendering settings.
```

[The doc.](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/Basic/visualization.html#Function-draw_geometries)